# How do you disallow same-origin access but allow strict cross-origin?

Tags: django-rest-framework, cors, django-cors-headers

Say I have a server abc:8080
and a website web.org that make requests to abc:8080..

I only want abc:8080 to be accessible through web.org..
Users are disallowed from navigating to abc:8080 without being on the allowed origin 'web.org'.
Is this possible?

django-cors-headers specific answer would be awesome!

Answer (score -1):

From what I understood is that your **abc:8080** is acting as a backend server providing APIs and **web.org** is let's say your frontend server consuming those APIs.

I assume you have `django-cors-headers` installed on **abc:8080**

Adding **web.org** to django settings variable **CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS** in **'abc:8080'** project should do the job

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "web.org",
    
]
```

Comment: Yep I have those set. Those only enable strict allowing access from web.org, but it still doesn't prevent abc:8080 from being accessed on its own.. there's no way to prevent same origin however. So a user could still navigate to abc:8080.

Comment: I believe the answer is, CORS is unable to provide such functionality. So I will need some other solution.

Comment: First things first why do you want to prevent access from the same origin?

And as the accronym CORS it self is about cross origin, I firmly believe it can not do anything about same origin access.

Comment: Just for some more obfuscation.. false sense of security